# Skyrim Sprint Glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim and after I killed a dragon, my sprint started acting wonky. It acts like the "Evade" Armor Ability from Halo: Reach. If you're a PS3 user, "Evade" is a quick boost of speed in any direction. I've tried reloading a save and restarting my 360. Can someone help?

Comment: This sounds like the Sneak Perk *Silent Roll*. Do you have that perk?

Comment: That perk requires you to be crouching (stealth stance) to trigger, else you should just sprint normally.

Comment: I actually don't level up the sneak skill tree. Also, after "Evading", as I am now dubbing it, it looks like I'm noticibly shorter, until I go into 3rd person.